# How to Convert Hexadecimal to Integer in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm seeing argument error when tried to convert hexadecimal to string using `List.to_integer`

```
iex(1)> List.to_integer("C5",16)
** (ArgumentError) argument error
:erlang.list_to_integer("C5", 16)
```

The same works in erlang

```
3> list_to_integer("C5", 16).
197
```

Comment: You should probably fix the wording in the question. You are trying convert to _integer_, not to _binary_ neither to _string_.

Answer (score 5):

Quotes matter.

```rb
List.to_integer('C5', 16)
#⇒ 197
```

In Elixir [`charlist`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#charlists) should be put into single quotes. Double quotes are reserved for binaries.

---

If you want to convert a binary to integer, one option would be to go through `charlist`:

```rb
"C5" |> to_charlist() |> List.to_integer(16)
#⇒ 197
```

Another option would be to [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Integer.html#parse/2):

```rb
with {result, _} <- Integer.parse("C5", 16), do: result
#⇒ 197
```

Answer (score 3):

In Elixir, characters surrounded by double quotes are strings, not lists, so you need to use `String.to_integer` instead of `List.to_integer`:

```
iex(1)> String.to_integer("C5", 16)
197
```

---

Elixir "strings" are the same type as Erlang "binaries":

```
iex(2)> is_binary("C5")
true
```

If you use single quotes instead of double quotes, you get what Elixir calls a "charlist" and Erlang calls a "string" - that is, a list of integers corresponding to Unicode codepoints:

```
iex(3)> is_list('C5')
true
iex(4)> [a, b] = 'C5'
'C5'
iex(5)> a
67
iex(6)> b
53
```